# Access a Mac's share remotely

Tags: network, macos, sharing

I want to connect to my Sierra Mac from another external location, but not with Screen Sharing/VNC but just like when I connect within my local network and view shared folders/files. I have an external shared USB Seagate drive that I need to access most of the time from other locations. Now I had my provider setup a static public IP address and he opened port 631. I also gave him the Mac's local IP address 192.168.x.xxx

I am definitely missing something here and the guy that opened the port does not know much about Macs. Bottom line.... what am I doing wrong because if I type the external IP address xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:631....it just connects to the CUP printer service.

---

The sharing protocols in use are SMB and AFP. The router model is: MikroTik FB20111L

Comment: That's because CUPS actually runs on port 631 :-) Which method are you using to access sharing (aka from what kind of system are you connecting and how exactly)? Different sharing protocols use different ports etc. so details are important here.

Comment: file sharing on mac is with smb and afp. external drive (seagate) is connected with usb.
I hope this helps..and thanks!
Router is mikrotik fb20111L

Comment: On the [MikroTik](https://www.mikrotik.com/) site I can only find a RB2011L router board but no FB20111L!

Comment: sorry it is RB2011L

Comment: @Robert Is it really this one [RB2011L](https://routerboard.com/rb2011l). Probably there is some kind of enclosure around it!

Comment: not sure what you mean by enclosure. is there a way to do what I am trying to accomplish? I am sure there is